# How is twisted's Deferred implemented?

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, twisted.web

Does it spawn a new thread underneath? If classical web server spawns a thread to serve a HTTP request and with Twisted web I have to spawn a Deferred() each time I want to query mysql - where's the gain? Looks like it doesn't make sens if it spawned a thread, so how's it implemented?

Comment: Have you looked at the source?

Comment: If what you really want is to understand AIO, that's a bigger question, and not one that's really about Deferred (or Twisted, or even Python). While there are newer approaches, you might start by reading about the `select()` call, and the `O_NONBLOCK` flag.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, a `Deferred` on its own is just a promise of a value, and a list of things to do when the value arrives (or when there is a failure getting the value).

How they work is like this: some function sees that the value it wants to return is not yet ready. So it prepares a Deferred, and then arranges somehow for that Deferred to be *called back* ("fired") with the value once it's ready. That second part is what may be causing your confusion; Deferreds on their own don't control when or how they are fired. It's the responsibility of whatever created the Deferred.

In the context of a whole Twisted app, nearly everything is event-based, and events are managed by the reactor. Say your code used `twisted.web.client.getPage()`, so it now has a Deferred that will be fired with the result of the http fetch. What that means is that `getPage()` started up a tcp conversation with the http server, and essentially installed handlers in the reactor saying "if you see any traffic on this tcp connection, call a method on this Protocol object". And once the Protocol object sees that it has received the whole page you asked for, it fires your Deferred, whereupon your own code is invoked via that Deferred's callback chain.

So everything is callbacks and hooks, all the way down. This is why you should never have blocking code in a Twisted app, unless on a separate thread- because it will stop everything else from being handled too.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

A `Deferred` in Python doesn't do anything, it doesn't have anything to do with threads or processes or anything else.

It is an abstraction of a *promise* for future data to be delivered and how that data is mapped to the receiving callback functions.

[This is documented very well.](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html)

How to Twisted achieves async behavior is documented very well on the Twisted documentation and newsgroup archives, simple Google searches will find what you need. It has nothing to do with the implementation of Deferred. If you still don't understand you need to ask that in another question for specific information, not in a comment to this answer.

That said, Twisted is kind of dead as far as concurrency goes, it will never scale to multi-core processors as well as something like Erlang, which is what I moved to from Twisted when Twisted quit scaling for me.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not precise. I meant: how's the non-blocking stuff implemented where - for instance - I query MySQL using twisted.enterprise.adbapi or other interfaces to other databases (cassandra, memcache etc.) Code execution is not blocked and at the same time it connects to database and runs the query. So I wanted to know if implementation underneath creates a new thread?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This isn't really on topic for the question, but you're not quite right about Twisted scaling. With PyPy's ongoing implementation of STM, it should be possible to make an STM-enabled reactor which will actually parallelize handling of multiple callback chains.

Comment: We were running CPython and this was 7 years ago. Who would to run PyPy in a corporate production system responsible for hundreds of millions of transactions a day back then? or now? PyPY still has a GIL according to their own documentation on the transactional memory donations page. *"The GIL, or Global Interpreter Lock, is a single lock in both CPython and (so far) PyPy, that all threads must acquire in order to execute Python bytecodes. This means that so far, in Python, even when using threads we do not gain any benefit in term of multicore performance."* so I am correct at this time.

Comment: I wasn't talking about 7 years ago. I was responding to your now-deleted comment which said something like "Twisted will never scale to multi-core processors".